# multiple tasks using python asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have the following code:

```
import asyncio

async def test_1():      
    res1 = await foo1()
    return res1

async def test_2():      
    res2 = await foo2()
    return res2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete([test_1, test_2]))
```

---

But the last call to `.run_until_complete()` is not working. How can I perform an async call to multiple tasks using `.run_until_complete()`?

Answer (score 18):

I was looking for examples and I found the answer. We can run a simple tasks, which gathers multiple coroutines:

```
import asyncio    

async def test_1(dummy):
  res1 = await foo1()
  return res1

async def test_2(dummy):
  res2 = await foo2()
  return res2

async def multiple_tasks(dummy):
  input_coroutines = [test_1(dummy), test_2(dummy)]
  res = await asyncio.gather(*input_coroutines, return_exceptions=True)
  return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  res1, res2 = loop.run_until_complete(multiple_tasks(dummy=0))
```

Comment: This gives me `RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread'.`